# continue task on ActivityOne after ActivityTwo calls finish()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that has a slider in it. From inside the view, onSomeSlideDistance I launch an activity. So my design is `ActivityOne => ListView => Adapter => CustomView => [sliding: intent] => ActivityTwo`.
Now my problem is this:

When the sliding action starts ActivityTwo, I need it to stay open (i.e. slid) until after ActivityTwo starts. But if user clicks to finish() ActivityTwo, when control returns to ActivityOne I need the slider to have reset. How do I accomplish this?

what have I tried?

I tried using a handler inside CustomView, but even when I use postDelayed and put the handler code after startActivity, the handler code still executes before ActivityTwo is started.

I tried using a inner activity inside CustomView and then from inside the inner activity call startActivityForResult(ActivityTwo.class,CODE), but this throws all sorts of errors as I tried different configurations for it.

At some point I also tried a delayed runnable in new Thread from within CustomView; so that it would run after ActivityTwo starts, then I get error about only activity can change its views.

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult() with onActivityResult() overridden sounds like exactly what you need, but if you've tried that already you might want to try this:

If your ActivityOne is paused by launching ActivityTwo you could set a flag in ActivityOne before you start the ActivityTwo Intent. Then in the onResume() of ActivityOne you can check the flag and if it's set close the slider and reset the flag.